# @RefreshScope Annotation return an empty data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I Was following this tutorial on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/Fq85GschdLw?t=1536) I have been able to successfully run the config server where I host two properties files here [File hosted](https://github.com/waploaj/Microservice-cloud-config-server). and on the client side when I tried to consume the value I get an empty response here is the dummy controller I have created.

```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
@RefreshScope
public class TestController {

    @Value("${test.name}")
    private String product;

    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        return product;
    }
}
```

but when I send a get request to route /api/test, I get a response of 200OK with no actual test value. name, What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: Does it return actual text without: @RefreshScope ?

Comment: Did you put a value in your application.properties (or application.yml) for "test.name" ?

I think the name of your property file should match some default pattern.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Comment: @TalGlik yes it returned the text that a pass on value annotation. But with /actuator/refresh it return "spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled"
]

Comment: @DavidPi yes if I put @value(${test. name}) it crashes, but when I put @Value("${propertySources:source test.name}" it returns "source test.name" but I want to return the actual value of test.name on cloud config server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial in youtube uses the default naming convetion but you probably have changed it and now spring cloud config server does not know which property file expects your service to have.

In cloud config server the file is saved as `product.properties`.

For this reason if your client service has some other name, this will not work. To correct it go to the client application and in `bootstrap.yaml` add the property `spring.application.name: product`.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I found the other reason I was not able to access the variable I was missing spring.cloud.config.client so it was not connected to any host. However is there any books on spring would recommend :)